# Authentication for redis-benchmark

Tags: database, caching, redis, redis-benchmark

I was trying to learn redis and i am stuck. I am new to redis and I have got no idea how to resolve this. I am not quite sure how to get authenticated for redis-benchmark. Do have a look into this.
[Redis Benchmark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Holl.png)

How do I get authenticated? Thank you for the reply in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Pass them in as command arguments just like with `redis-cli`. `-a` sets the password. `--user` sets the username, if you have one:

```bash
redis-benchmark --user username -a foobared
```

You can get a list of the the arguments by using the `--help` flag:

```bash
redis-benchmark --help
```